# AADToken: HTTP connection to https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token failed for getting token from AzureAD

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to get access to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 from Azure Databricks Cluster - SCALA version, via mount point in filesystem.

I tried the following code where azure service principal credentials are designated as entry point to azure subscription (role --> storage blob data owner ON Data Lake containers).

```
val fileSystemName = "XXXXXXXXXX"
val storageAccountName = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
val appID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
val appSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
val tenantID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

val configs = Map(
  "fs.azure.account.auth.type" -> "OAuth",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type" -> "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id" -> "<appID>",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret" -> "<appSecret>",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint" -> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token")

// Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<fileSystemName>@<storageAccountName>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mountPoint = "/mnt/raw-container",
  extraConfigs = configs)
```

But get this error message :

```
shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator$HttpException: HTTP Error 400; url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token' AADToken: HTTP connection to https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token failed for getting token from AzureAD.; requestId=''; contentType='text/html; charset=us-ascii'; response '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">


<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
'
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenSingleCall(AzureADAuthenticator.java:372)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenCall(AzureADAuthenticator.java:270)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenUsingClientCreds(AzureADAuthenticator.java:95)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureOAuth(DBUtilsCore.scala:477)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureFileSystem(DBUtilsCore.scala:488)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.mount(DBUtilsCore.scala:446)
    at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.DbfsUtilsImpl.mount(DbfsUtilsImpl.scala:85)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3300122855614219:18)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3300122855614219:67)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3300122855614219:69)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3300122855614219:71)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3300122855614219:73)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$read$$iw.<init>(command-3300122855614219:75)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$read.<init>(command-3300122855614219:77)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$read$.<init>(command-3300122855614219:81)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$read$.<clinit>(command-3300122855614219)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at linec1d28633ab4c4f2d9530ae7396d8282327.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:570)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:714)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:667)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$10(DriverLocal.scala:396)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:230)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:268)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:653)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:645)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:486)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:598)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:391)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems there is an endpoint authentication issue.

---

**If the question helped, up-vote it. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Try to add the role to the service principal at the storage account level instead of container level, will it work?

Comment: Yes, permission is set as "Storage Blob Data owner" at storage account level.

Comment: I also tried with : "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint" -> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token" but same error message.

Comment: I can also see HTTP error 400 : Invalid URL, which means bad request syntax. I don't know where there is the issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the problem differently and it works....

I provisioned an azure databricks PREMIUM version

Then, at Python cluster configuration page I checked "Enable credential passthrough for user-level data access" option under "Azure Data Lake Storage Credential Passthrough" at "Advanced Options" section.

So I only have to pass the moint point script in a cell and it works :

```
storageaccountName = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
storagecontainerName = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

configs = { 
    "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "CustomAccessToken", 
    "fs.azure.account.custom.token.provider.class": spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.passthrough.adls.gen2.tokenProviderClassName")
}

# Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point. 

dbutils.fs.mount( 
    source = "abfss://"+storagecontainerName+"@"+storageaccountName+".dfs.core.windows.net/", 
    mount_point = "/mnt/raw-container", 
    extra_configs = configs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that you have well copied the tenant_id not the Object ID,

there are some thing called the tenant_id.

I did that mistakes